# Undefined method 'request_uri'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working with the [Shopsense Ruby Gem](https://github.com/w2davids/Shopsense) however I am unable to use the gem.  Making requests exactly as in the [test](https://github.com/w2davids/Shopsense/blob/master/test/test_shopsense.rb) I receive the following error:

```
/Users/rudolph9/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:455:in `block in get_response': undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x007fd5b3a66810> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/rudolph9/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from /Users/rudolph9/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:454:in `get_response'
    from /Users/rudolph9/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/Shopsense-0.1.1/lib/Shopsense.rb:76:in `do_search'
    from test_shopsense.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

However, the test works fine if I clone the repository, modify the test and require the source directly as follows:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env ruby¬                                                                                                                                                       
2 require 'rubygems'¬
3 #require 'Shopsense'¬
4 require '../lib/shopsense.rb'¬
.
.
.
```

What is the issue when using the gem it self??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an older version of the gem installed, or another gem which is named Shopsense?

With the error you're getting, I suspect the issue would be related ruby trying to automatically find the gem when you do `require 'Shopsense'` and finding something other than what you want. When you do `require '../lib/shopsense.rb'` it defines a specific path to the gem, so you always get the gem you want.

I don't have any experience with Shopsense, but the link you supplied looks like its a version `0.1.0`, while the ruby interpreter found a `Shopsense-0.1.1`. I suspect the issue has to do with that. In fact, the source for Shopsense you linked to, line 76 (where the error is in your output) is a blank line.

Comment: no it's definitely `0.1.1` gem list -> Shopsense (0.1.1)... `require 'Shopsense-0.1.1'` gives me a load error as well.

Comment: @KurtRudolph Where are you getting the source for the test from though? The github link you posted doesn't look like it could possibly generate that error, since lib/shopsense.rb:76 is blank space.

If you're running example code from that github link, but its including a different version of shopsense, that would explain the issue.

Comment: ahhh, although it is installed as 0.1.1 I think it's actually 0.1.0.  Looking a little deeper `Shopsense/pkg/Shopsense-0.1.0/lib/shopsense.rb`.  Thanks!  I'm not exactly sure how Gems are set up, could you direct me to a good tutorial so I may fix this?

Comment: Hopefully the RubyGem documentation will give you the help for that: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/2#page6.